# Draw MFCC Feature Extraction Waveform

Tags: java, voice-recognition, voice

I have an application that used MFCC as the algorithm, after do some feature extraction, it will results double array data, I need to know how to draw this double array MFCC feature extraction result in waveform. the MFCC feature extraction steps is like this :

Remove DC --> Pre Emphasize --> Frame Blocking --> FilterBank --> DCT --> Cepstral Liftering --> Remove Silence

and the result of this feature extractions is something like this in double array variable :

27.462483910166856,-4.027354580150781,50.069227915352684,-12.317832866411996,48.499715973587726,-9.009800900826418,17.99003841099071,-4.522968782225892,1.3956929138408378,31.4052894799513,-7.218960149074669,54.25092519804543,-10.570010628188196,44.42664671741103,-5.624907629716297,19.610325289195902,-0.5849468266396151,2.9093623346208637,28.86000241746882,-6.966066761633022,52.89727618984855,-15.59787917823046

Can anyone explain or give some resource or guide to draw the waveform from this result??

Comment: Such questions are better asked on http://dsp.stackexchange.com. You can draw features, but you will not be able to see anything from them. The DCT transform makes them "gaussian", so essentially a white noise. The inverse transform from MFCC features is possible, though not trivial, you can google about MLSA filter and check SPTK toolkit.

Comment: Hello Shmyrev, thanks for reply, can you explain to me what's that mean I am not able to see anything from them? I have seen many paper about MFCC and I see that they can draw the waveform before and after doing the future extraction, but I can't find how they do that specially in Java. Can you help me? I have post this question in dsp stackexchange too like your suggestion.

Comment: Well, it is not quite clear what do you mean by "before and after". You should probably give a link on exact paper you are talking about.

Comment: can you share the link, you are following?